# Do file paths get built into projects when building a wix installer from visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, wix, xml-validation

I've developed a simple web application in asp.net using visual studio 2015, and built an installer in order to install the project on another server. After installing the web application on another server I noticed that one of the errors I'm getting from that application is referring to a specific file in a file path that doesn't exist on the server that I've installed the application on:

```
XmlValidator::ValidateXml() - Error Validating xml - System.Exception:  Validation error: The element 'balances' in namespace 'http://www.alpha.com/xyz/schemas/v1.0/' has invalid child element 'progressive' in namespace 'http://www.alpha.com/xyz/schemas/v1.0/'.

   at ABC.Common.XMLValidators.XmlValidator.ValidationHandler(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) in C:\R2A Src\Dev\R2A\R2A[Dev]\R2AWebServices\R2A.Common\XmlValidator.cs:line 142
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ElementValidationError(XmlQualifiedName name, ValidationState context, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, String sourceUri, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElementContext(XmlQualifiedName elementName, Boolean& invalidElementInContext)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElement(String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, String xsiType, String xsiNil, String xsiSchemaLocation, String xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation)
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at ABC.Common.XMLValidators.XmlValidator.ValidateXml(String sXmlToValidate, G2SClass bgadsClass, Int32 hostId, String egmId, String& outXmlMsg) in C:\R2A Src\Dev\R2A\R2A[Dev]\R2AWebServices\R2A.Common\XmlValidator.cs:line 93
```

C:\R2A Src\Dev\R2A\R2A[Dev]\R2AWebServices\R2A.Common\XmlValidator.cs is a file on my personal computer that I built the project on. I've looked through the code and that file path isn't hard coded anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Exception shows developer's path instead of servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899644/exception-shows-developers-path-instead-of-servers)

The info is stored in the pbd files generated during compilation. There goes my lead....

Comment: FWIW, this isn't really a WiX issue.  This is .NET behavior in general.