# How to remove developer's machine paths from log messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, build, pdb-files

When I publish a ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 application, the logs of exceptions contain the path of the developers machine.

Example of a log:

```
2021-04-27 16:36:47.1954 | |18f76390-4123opr9fjnfe832. | ERROR | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware | An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. | System.Exception: TEST
   at ClassLibrary.Repositories.HomeRepo.GetSummary() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 68
   at ClassLibrary.Services.HomeService.GetStatuses() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 38
   at Project.Controllers.HomeController.GetSummary() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......\HomeController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   ......
   ......
```

The line number and file location is useful to identify causes of bugs, but the path includes the developer's name `FLASTNAME` and I'd prefer if that wasn't there.

The closest thing my research lead me to is .pdb files ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8899644/12300287), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139276/12300287)), some suggesting to change the debugging information in build settings:

[image]

However, I tried every option but it still shows the full paths. I don't have the option to build the project on another machine, so what could I do in this case?

I know I'm probably misunderstanding something here, but even building project in `Release` configuration doesn't solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

Here is the result of @Kirk Larkin's suggestion to add `<PathMap>` code

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PathMap>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=ANOTHERPATH</PathMap>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to project's csproj file:

```
2021-04-27 16:36:47.1954 | |18f76390-4123opr9fjnfe832. | ERROR | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware | An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. | System.Exception: TEST
   at ClassLibrary.Repositories.HomeRepo.GetSummary() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 68
   at ClassLibrary.Services.HomeService.GetStatuses() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 38
   at Project.Controllers.HomeController.GetSummary() in ANOTHERPATH\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   ......
   ......
```

So it only affected the path for the `HomeController` part in the trace. This is similar to what happens if I set *Debugging information* to `None` in *Advanced Build Settings*:

```
2021-04-27 16:36:47.1954 | |18f76390-4123opr9fjnfe832. | ERROR | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware | An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. | System.Exception: TEST
   at ClassLibrary.Repositories.HomeRepo.GetSummary() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 68
   at ClassLibrary.Services.HomeService.GetStatuses() in C:\Users\FLASTNAME\TFS\dotnet\APPNAME\.......:line 38
   at Project.Controllers.HomeController.GetSummary()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   ......
   ......
```

except here I don't get any path or the line number for the `HomeController` part.

Comment: If you're building in CI, there's some settings for Deterministic Builds that will convert those PDB paths to relative to the Source Root path. You may want to look into that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are not actually building in CI.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239792/is-it-possible-to-override-or-clear-the-debug-path-in-a-dll-build-with-new-cspro and let us know if that works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @KirkLarkin, we were able to solve my issue.

The best option for me was to create a single [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-example) file under the solution (the *Solution Items* folder was generated automatically):

[image]

My Directory.Build.props file has the following code:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PathMap>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)=$(MSBuildProjectName)</PathMap>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

which will map each project's build directory to be just the project's name, resulting in the desired shortened paths:

```
2021-04-27 16:36:47.1954 | |18f76390-4123opr9fjnfe832. | ERROR | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware | An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. | System.Exception: TEST
   at ClassLibrary.Repositories.HomeRepo.GetSummary() in ClassLibrary\.......:line 68
   at ClassLibrary.Services.HomeService.GetStatuses() in ClassLibrary\.......:line 38
   at Project.Controllers.HomeController.GetSummary() in Project\.......\HomeController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   ......
   ......
```

If you need to do this for only one project, you can instead edit the project's .csproj file to contain the `<PathMap>` code nested inside a `<PropertyGroup>` tag.